# Double triggering QEvent::KeyPress and QEvent::KeyRelease

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a problem: I'm trying to catch a keystroke.
I use eventFilter:

```
bool Inf_int_qt::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
//  ::SoundKeys(event);
    this->SoundKeys(event);
    return true;
}
```

Next I do the following checks:

```
void Inf_int_qt::SoundKeys(QEvent* event)
{
    
if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress || event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease) 
{
    bool p_press =  event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress;

    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
    if( keyEvent->isAutoRepeat() ) 
        return;

    switch (keyEvent->key())
    {

    case Qt::Key_Control:
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
}
```

In the end, when I quickly press (and release) the ctrl button, I get as many as 4 QEvent triggers:

1. QEvent::KeyPress
2. QEvent::KeyPress
3. QEvent::KeyRelease
4. QEvent::KeyRelease

It turns out that each signal is generated twice. I can't understand anything. Why can it work like this? OC Win 10. Qt 5.8.0

Comment: How do you know which events are triggered? By the way, are they triggered for the same object or for different ones?

Comment: In the first two stops I have `bool p_press = event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress;` equal to true, after false. From what I conclude that the sequence is exactly as I described it. Yes, the object is the same.

Comment: @vahancho hm. I think I made a mistake. The pointers point to 2 different objects for each QEvent pair. But i dont understand how i can fix it.. Thank you, it became clear where the root of the problem is

Comment: It's probably a hierarchy of widgets that trigger the event (from child to parent). In your event filter you should consider only the object that you are interested in.

Comment: I thought that too. But because the event filter returns `true`, the event should be considered as successfully handled and shoud not be propagated along the widget hierarchy.